# llamada get en ionic 2

Tags: ionic, angularjs-2.0, typescript

Buenas, soy nuevo en ésto de angular 2 e ionic 2 y no comprendo bien la teoria de los construcctores y algunas cosas.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
  


 
export class User {
  name: string;
  email: string;
 
  constructor(name: string, email: string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
  }
}
 
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  currentUser: User;

  public login(credentials) {
    if (credentials.email === null || credentials.password === null) {
      return Observable.throw("Please insert credentials");
    } else {
      
 var url = 'https://apibioidcrear.azurewebsites.net/Usuario/GetUsuario/2';
 var response = this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
 console.log(response);

      return Observable.create(observer => {
        // At this point make a request to your backend to make a real check!
        let access = (credentials.password === "pass" && credentials.email === "email");
        this.currentUser = new User('Alexis Nichel', 'alexis@test.com');
        observer.next(access);
        observer.complete();
      });
    }
  }
 
  public register(credentials) {
    if (credentials.email === null || credentials.password === null) {
      return Observable.throw("Please insert credentials");
    } else {
      // At this point store the credentials to your backend!
      return Observable.create(observer => {
        observer.next(true);
        observer.complete();
      });
    }
  }
 
  public getUserInfo() : User {
    return this.currentUser;
  }
 
  public logout() {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      this.currentUser = null;
      observer.next(true);
      observer.complete();
    });
  }
}
```

y no logro que ésta parte funcione:

```html
 var url = 'https://apibioidcrear.azurewebsites.net/Usuario/GetUsuario/2';
 var response = this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
 console.log(response);
```

No logro hacer que me reconozca el http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el constructor de tu clase donde defines `constructor(name: string, email: string)`, deberías crear una variable `http` que haga referencia al tipo de dato `Http` que estás importando del *Angular*:

```
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
```

Quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
constructor (name: string, email: string, http: Http)
```